# difference between scope and namespace of ruby-on-rails 3 routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't understand what the difference is between a namespace and a scope in the routing of ruby-on-rails 3.

Could someone please explain?

```
namespace "admin" do
  resources :posts, :comments
end

scope :module => "admin" do
  resources :posts, :comments
end
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The difference lies in the paths generated.

The paths are `admin_posts_path` and `admin_comments_path` for the namespace, while they are just `posts_path` and `comments_path` for the scope.

You can get the same result as a namespace by passing the `:name_prefix` option to scope.

Comment: by paths u mean the helper names right? i don't understand the scope's functionality. what does it (:module => "admin") do if nothing change?

Comment: It changes the actual paths used by the route paths to "/admin/whatever", just like namespace. The only different is the prefix added to the helper methods.

Comment: To better understand the difference: consider using scopes for localization via URL and namespacing for nesting, for example the url:http://domain.com/nl/admin/panel. The nl is a scope, and admin is a namespace.

Comment: I also get the same result passing `:as` instead of `:name_prefix` to `scope` as follows: `scope module: "admin", as: "admin"`, I'm not sure about any other effects though.

Answer (score 72):

examples always help me, so here is an example:

```
namespace :blog do
  resources :contexts
end
```

will give us the following routes:

```
    blog_contexts GET    /blog/contexts(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"blog/contexts"}
                  POST   /blog/contexts(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"blog/contexts"}
 new_blog_context GET    /blog/contexts/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"blog/contexts"}
edit_blog_context GET    /blog/contexts/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"blog/contexts"}
     blog_context GET    /blog/contexts/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"blog/contexts"}
                  PUT    /blog/contexts/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"blog/contexts"}
                  DELETE /blog/contexts/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"blog/contexts"}
```

Using scope...

```
scope :module => 'blog' do
  resources :contexts
end
```

Will give us:

```
     contexts GET    /contexts(.:format)           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"blog/contexts"}
              POST   /contexts(.:format)           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"blog/contexts"}
  new_context GET    /contexts/new(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"blog/contexts"}
 edit_context GET    /contexts/:id/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"blog/contexts"}
      context GET    /contexts/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"blog/contexts"}
              PUT    /contexts/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"blog/contexts"}
              DELETE /contexts/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"blog/contexts"}
```

Here is some good reading on the subject: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing

Comment: So if you didn't use scope here and just had: resources :contexts, the controller wouldn't be nested on blog: blog/contexts

Answer (score 59):

from the [rails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

"The namespace scope will automatically add `:as` as well as `:module` and `:path` prefixes."

so

```
namespace "admin" do
  resources :contexts
end
```

is the same as

```
scope "/admin", as: "admin", module: "admin" do
  resources :contexts
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Both **scope** and **namespace** are scoping a set of routes to the given default options.
Except that there are no default options for **scope**, and for **namespace**
`:path`, `:as`, `:module`, `:shallow_path` and `:shallow_prefix` options all default to the name of the namespace.

[Available options](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match) for both **scope** and **namespace** correspond to those of **match**.

Answer (score 1):

**scope** is bit complex, but provides more options to fine-tune exactly what you want to do.

**scope** supports three **options: module, path and as**. If you see scope with all it options, it will be exactly same as namespace.

In other words, routes generated by

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :posts
end
```

is same as

```
scope module: 'admin', path: 'admin', as: 'admin' do
  resources :posts
end
```

In other words, we can say that there are no default options for **scope** as compared to namespace. **namespace** add all these options by default. Thus using scope, we can more fine tune the routes as required.

If you take a deep look into **scope** and **namespace** default behaviour, you will find that **scope** by default supports only **:path** option, where as **namespace** supports three options **module, path and as** by default.

For more info, please refer a doc [namespace-and-routing](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing).

Comment: And if you're trying to put, for any reason, a required params, scope is the best solution.