# NoMethodError in Admin::Post#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've used **[this tutorial](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)** to transfer some controllers in a single file.

```
Showing /home/action/NAME/app/views/admin/posts/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `admin_posts_path' for #<#<Class:...

...

<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
```

routes file:

```
scope module: 'admin' do
  resources :posts
end
```

posts_controller.rb

```
def new
  @post = Admin::Post.new
end
```

Comment: Change it to namespace :admin do instead of scope.

Comment: Also run rake:routes. You can see what is being generated

Comment: with rake:routes, it generates routes like 'new_post' or 'posts'. What is the problem with scope module?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029954/difference-between-scope-and-namespace-of-ruby-on-rails-3-routing. Basically you need to change the path name. You can pass url: new_post

Comment: what should I change? I use 'new_post_path' to add a new post; that's what is supported by using scope.

Comment: You need to do form_for @post, url: new_post_path do |f|. Etc

Comment: My answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666582/routing-error-no-route-matches-post-comments-new-using-scope question should take care of this issue as well.