# Routing Error No route matches [POST] "/comments/new" - using scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Error appears when I try to submit the comment.

routes.rb file:

```
scope module: 'admin' do 
  resources :comments
end
```

_form

```
<%= form_for new_comment_path do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  ...

 <%= submit_tag 'Submit', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>

<% end %>
```

comments_controller.rb

```
def new
  @comment = Admin::Comment.new
end

def create
  @comment = Admin::Comment.new(comment_params)

  ...

end
```

Comment: do you have a 'new' action in your comments controller?

Comment: in your console run rake routes command and see if the route is described there

Comment: I did that and I see 'new_comment_path'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<%= form_for(@comment, url: comments_path) do |f| %>
```

As you need to post the form, you need a POST route. This will automatically POST your form to `create` action(`comments_path`). Logically `new` form should be posted to `create` action of your controller.

`new_comment_path` refers to `GET` route of new page which you are trying to use on form. It is not a `POST` route so you get the error.

```
new_comment GET    /comments/new(.:format)   admin/comments#new
            POST   /comments(.:format)    admin/comments#create  ## You need this route
```

### Alternatively:

Define your routes as below:

```
namespace :admin do 
  resources :comments
end
```

and you can use `form_for` as

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
```

Comment: When I use that, I get ` undefined method 'admin_comments_path' `

Comment: The weird thing is, however, that he already said that this didn't solve anything. He should still define it like this though.

Comment: I can access the form, but when I try to submit it, I get 'param not found: comment'

Comment: My answer resolves your Original Question. Please accept the same. As for the `param not found: comment` goes, there might be an issue with your controller code. You can post another question for the same. Otherwise we'll just keep chaining questions in comments which is not good in SO. I or someone else would gladly help you on the other issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to use:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @comment] do |f| %>
```

Here's a good reference: [form_for and scopes, rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741979/form-for-and-scopes-rails-3)

Comment: I get this error - undefined method `admin_admin_comments_path' -

Comment: Why not try just `@comment`

Comment: Then I get - undefined method 'admin_comments_path' - . When I run rake routes, I only see 'new_comments_path' (no admin)