# Namespace / Module Undefined Variable (Route), I See It In Rake Output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, namespaces

Quick Overview:

I think I'm getting myself into a mess from namespacing...

I've created a generator that generates pretty much an engine.

I'm getting an undefined method for a route I've created, but I see it in my rake routes.

A little more:

My generator creates these routes:

```
namespace :shifted_commerce do
  resources :items
  resources :base_items
  resource :cart, only: [:show, :update, :destroy] do
        resource :order, only: [:show, :create, :update, :edit, :new
  end
end
```

The controllers are now nested in `app/controllers/shifted_commerce/(controller_name)`

Here is my index action on my base_item controller:

```
def index
    @base_items = ShiftedCommerce::BaseItem.all
    @line_item = ShiftedCommerce::LineItem.new
    @cart = current_cart
    @title = "Store"
end
```

As you can see, I've namespaced the models as well.

```
    class ShiftedCommerce::BaseItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    {...}
    end
```

I have my app routing to the above action via

```
root 'shifted_commerce/base_items#index'
```

I get an error on the page load:

```
 undefined local variable or method `new_base_item_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe26ea77940>:0x007fe26c580a10>
```

Can it be the class `#<#<Class:0x007fe26ea77940>:0x007fe26c580a10>`?  I'm not sure how to debug this issue.

The code I am calling the route from:

```
{...}
<%= link_to "New Item", new_shifted_commerce_base_item_path %>
```

My Routes are as Follows

```
                          Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                     Controller#Action
          shifted_commerce_items GET    /shifted_commerce/items(.:format)               shifted_commerce/items#index
                                 POST   /shifted_commerce/items(.:format)               shifted_commerce/items#create
       new_shifted_commerce_item GET    /shifted_commerce/items/new(.:format)           shifted_commerce/items#new
      edit_shifted_commerce_item GET    /shifted_commerce/items/:id/edit(.:format)      shifted_commerce/items#edit
           shifted_commerce_item GET    /shifted_commerce/items/:id(.:format)           shifted_commerce/items#show
                                 PATCH  /shifted_commerce/items/:id(.:format)           shifted_commerce/items#update
                                 PUT    /shifted_commerce/items/:id(.:format)           shifted_commerce/items#update
                                 DELETE /shifted_commerce/items/:id(.:format)           shifted_commerce/items#destroy
     shifted_commerce_base_items GET    /shifted_commerce/base_items(.:format)          shifted_commerce/base_items#index
                                 POST   /shifted_commerce/base_items(.:format)          shifted_commerce/base_items#create
  new_shifted_commerce_base_item GET    /shifted_commerce/base_items/new(.:format)      shifted_commerce/base_items#new
 edit_shifted_commerce_base_item GET    /shifted_commerce/base_items/:id/edit(.:format) shifted_commerce/base_items#edit
      shifted_commerce_base_item GET    /shifted_commerce/base_items/:id(.:format)      shifted_commerce/base_items#show
                                 PATCH  /shifted_commerce/base_items/:id(.:format)      shifted_commerce/base_items#update
                                 PUT    /shifted_commerce/base_items/:id(.:format)      shifted_commerce/base_items#update
                                 DELETE /shifted_commerce/base_items/:id(.:format)      shifted_commerce/base_items#destroy
     shifted_commerce_cart_order POST   /shifted_commerce/cart/order(.:format)          shifted_commerce/orders#create
 new_shifted_commerce_cart_order GET    /shifted_commerce/cart/order/new(.:format)      shifted_commerce/orders#new
edit_shifted_commerce_cart_order GET    /shifted_commerce/cart/order/edit(.:format)     shifted_commerce/orders#edit
                                 GET    /shifted_commerce/cart/order(.:format)          shifted_commerce/orders#show
                                 PATCH  /shifted_commerce/cart/order(.:format)          shifted_commerce/orders#update
                                 PUT    /shifted_commerce/cart/order(.:format)          shifted_commerce/orders#update
           shifted_commerce_cart GET    /shifted_commerce/cart(.:format)                shifted_commerce/carts#show
                                 PATCH  /shifted_commerce/cart(.:format)                shifted_commerce/carts#update
                                 PUT    /shifted_commerce/cart(.:format)                shifted_commerce/carts#update
                                 DELETE /shifted_commerce/cart(.:format)                shifted_commerce/carts#destroy
                            root GET    /
```

Comment: Can you show your view, where `new_base_item_path` is used?

Comment: You've typed `an engine`. Is it an engine? I mean Rails [engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html).

Comment: I think so, in the gem where the generator is located in lib/shifted_commerce/engine.rb exists Ill post i.

Comment: So the error comes from main_app (where you've mounted your engine)?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm using an engine, i've only declared one in my gem.  My generator just declares a lot of named spaced models and controllers, but yes the error comes from the app that I'm using the gem in.

Comment: If so, I assume you've mounted your routes within main_app. Any of your engine routes are accessible via `engine_name.route_name` so in this case `shifted_commerce.new_base_item_path`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, I don't believe you're following the proper conventions for [namespacing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) controllers and actions.  According the the rails documentation you should be defining your routes like so:

```
namespace :shifted_commerce do
  resources :items
  resources :base_items
  resource :cart, only: [:show, :update, :destroy] do
    resource :order, only: [:show, :create, :update, :edit, :new]
  end
end
```

Then I believe the way you would access your action is:

```
new_shifted_commerce_base_item_path
```

You should really take a look at the rails routing [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).  It's pretty helpful and straight forward.  Also, here is a good stackoverflow post on the [difference between a namespace and a scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029954/difference-between-scope-and-namespace-of-ruby-on-rails-3-routing) in rails.

Comment: What does your `rake routes` output now?

Comment: I've updated it to show the new output -- The problem is the same, I see a match to the path, but it calls it an undefined local variable

Comment: Why are you providing the `path` and `controller` parameters in your route definitions?  They're not necessary as they are generated based on the name of the resource you're mapping.  My guess is those are screwing with rails somehow.

Comment: I'm not, I was, but I changed it after your answer... my routes are how they are presently defined.

Comment: And you restarted your server?

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it.  Something's still very wrong... I'm getting all kinds of name errors, sometimes I reload the page when changing .new to .all and then the error goes away...

Comment: That seems weird.  If you can be more specific I **may** be able to help.

Comment: you forgot the `do` after `namespace :shifted_commerce`