# scope in rails routes not prepending paramter in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, routes

I have a requirement that I have to append `abc/admin` in each url. for e.g.

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/abc/admin/admins/sign_in          # USING ADMIN AS DEVISE MODEL 
http://0.0.0.0:3000/abs/admin/products
http://0.0.0.0:3000/abs/admin/products/:id
http://0.0.0.0:3000/abs/admin/categories
```

etc. Now I tried with

```
scope "abc/admin" do
    resources :products, :categories
end
```

It creates some `URL` eg:

```
products GET    /abc/admin/products(.:format)                   products#index
         POST   /abc/admin/products(.:format)                   products#create
new_role GET    /abc/admin/products/new(.:format)               products#new
```

for `Admin` Model I tried using

```
scope "abc/admin" do
    devise_for :admins, :controllers => {:sessions=>"admin/sessions", :registrations=>'admin/registrations'}
end
```

It also create `URL` like:

```
admin_registration     POST   /abc/admin/admins(.:format)          admin/registrations#create
new_admin_registration GET    /abc/admin/admins/sign_up(.:format)  admin/registrations#new
```

Now `new_admin_registration_path` redirect to `http://0.0.0.0:3000/admins/sign_up` It is not considering the scope. I don't know how to achieve scope parameter in URL for devise as well as for other controller.

Comment: you can use `namespace` like `namespace "abc/admin" do     devise_for :admins, :controllers => {:sessions=>"admin/sessions", :registrations=>'admin/registrations'} end` once try that
`

Answer (score 0):

@Choco is right, you should only declare a namespace once. Then everything goes inside that single block.

```
namespace "abc/admin" do 
   resources :products, :categories
   devise_for :admins, :controllers => {:sessions=>"admin/sessions", :registrations=>'admin/registrations'} 
end
```

Then your path helper becomes new_abc_admin_admin_registration_path. See here for info: [difference between scope and namespace of ruby-on-rails 3 routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029954/difference-between-scope-and-namespace-of-ruby-on-rails-3-routing)

Comment: Well doing this I get `rake aborted!
ArgumentError: Invalid route name: 'abc/admin_products'` error. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: what path did you use? for products it would be: `abc_admin_products_path`