# How to set the correct resource name for devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a problem with the configuration of my Devise (`4.5.0`) in Rails (`5.2.1`). The login doesn't work via the api.

In my `routes.rb` I define the routes for Devise within a namespace like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    devise_for :users
  end

  [...]
end
```

This generates the correct routes, but the login doesn't work, because Devise thinks that the `resource_name` or scope is `api_user` instead of `user`. If I override the `auth_options` method I can fix this problem, but is it really the way to go?

## Update

I've investigated this further. It's possible to workaround this by adding `singular: :user` to the `devise_for` declaration. This isn't intuitive to me, why I created an issue: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4969

Comment: This question is little bit confusing. :-)
The problem is login not working because devise is not using user. So, I'm not sure this is you needed. Have you tried with `scope :api` instead of `namespace :api` in `routes.rb`?

Comment: Thank you @unlimitedfocus for your question. Yes the login is not working because devise picks up the wrong resource. I've also tried scope. It seems to be almost the same as namespace in this case according to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16243763/371530